# Keeping the scroll position while loading data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load more data in the table when user clicks on the "more" button but it takes the scroll position to the beginning of the table. I tried using `<a id="#placeholder"/>` and setting the `window.location.hash = "#placeholder"` or `$("#placeholder").click();` but nothing works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
`window.scrollTo(1, 0);`